# Есть чем полакомиться. Нужна здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

«Шмелю здесь есть чем полакомиться» – цельное по смыслу выражение?

Comment: Отметьте ответ как принятый, если он решил вашу проблему или помог в ее решении. Из каждых 10 вопросов вы в лучшем случае принимаете только один. Это можно как-то объяснить?

Comment: Простите, если я не знаю, что и где здесь нажимать...

Comment: Надо нажать "галочку" внизу,  под стрелками. Она, кстати, подписана.

Comment: Спасибо, поставила!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Обычно делается так. Вы принимаете ответ, если он вас полностью устраивает. Если есть какие-то сомнения, то можно подождать другие ответы. Если ответов несколько, то вы выбираете тот, который помог вам больше других.  Удачи вам в решении ваших проблем, ждем ваших новых вопросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Шмелю здесь есть чем полакомиться.***

Конечно, запятая не нужна! Это цельное по смыслу выражение.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm#%D0%B7_01

> Запятой не разделяются выражения типа **есть чем заняться**, есть над чем поработать, было о чем подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать, осталось на что жить и т.п., **состоящие из глагола быть, найти (найтись), остаться и немногих других в форме единственного или множественного числа, вопросительно-относительного местоимения или наречия (кто, что, где, куда, когда и т.п.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола**. Например:
> Бранить есть кому, кормить – некому (Даль); Есть чему и нравиться... (Писемский); Нашли чем удивить: и без вас все это видали; Он не нашелся что ответить и промолчал.